# Clicking a button via IE automation VBA

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, button

I have problem clicking the button from VBA using IE.
The page is
[http://trademap.org/Country_SelProduct_TS.aspx?nvpm=1|||||TOTAL|||2|1|1|1|2|1|2|1|1](http://trademap.org/Country_SelProduct_TS.aspx?nvpm=1%7C%7C%7C%7C%7CTOTAL%7C%7C%7C2%7C1%7C1%7C1%7C2%7C1%7C2%7C1%7C1)

All button I can click, and works fine except Previous/Next period [image]

The control ID is `ctl00_PageContent_GridViewPanelControl_ImageButton_Previous`

I tried several different methods but nothing worked.
Any help appreciate

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is a Javascript controlled button. You will need to use `div.FireEvent "onclick"` to trigger the event change.

Comment: Thank you, I will check with `div.FireEvent "onclick"`, I was try with 
`Set rpp = doc.getElementById("ctl00_PageContent_GridViewPanelControl_ImageButton_Previous")
rpp.FireEvent ("onclick")`
but didn't work